# Can you please help me identify this type of tea?

Tags: translation

I would like to identify the type of tea contained in this package:

[image]
[image]
I already identified the character "cha" on the label (circled in blue on the pictures above), but I have a hard time translating the sinograms adjacent to this character.

I already checked out the answers to [this related question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/%E8%8C%B6-how-to-identify-varieties-of-tea), but these did not help me translate the label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(SC: Simplified Chinese; 
TC: Traditional Chinese)

景谷 (SC and TC)

生态大树茶 (SC)

中國雲南勐河茶廠出品 (TC)

中國雲南省景谷縣
勐河茶廠出品
Jinggu County, Yunnan Province, China
Meng-he Tea Factory produced

生态 ecological
大树茶 big-tree tea

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer, user16115!